# Associate file type with Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, file, file-extension, file-association

I am creating a java swing application and I need to set the my program as the default program for the file extension `.mcsd` (MIME type `text/mcsd`). This *must* work on windows, and it would be nice if it worked on OS X/Linux as well. I am somewhat new to java (3 or 4 months) so please don't bombard me with all kinds of expert talk.

I have seen [associating a custom file extension with java app in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556476/associating-a-custom-file-extension-with-java-app-in-windows), but I would prefer not to use the Java Web Start. If possible, I would also like to know how to set the icon of that file type. I have found [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html) as a way of creating the `.exe` and plan to use it, but if is not the best tool for convertinf to an exe or someone knows something better feel free to tell me. Another thing: I need to be able to get the data from this file after the program has opened.

So my question is: ***how do I do this?***

Comment: Because I would like to have a native installer that just installs the program, without opening a web page or anything. If that's not how the we start works, then I'm happy to use it.

Comment: Would I do that using `openConnection()` on a URL object? and where could I find a tutorial on JNLP and JWS other than docs.oracle.com, I find those tutorials a little hard to read (it's not confusing, the look just does my head in).

Comment: And what about getting the data/path of the file that was opened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deploy the app. with [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info):

> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, **file associations,** automatic update ..

See the [file services demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) for an example of a JNLP that declares an interest in the `.zzz` file type.

This is how the association is declared in the JNLP:

```xml
<association
  extensions="zzz"
  mime-type="text/sleepytime" />
```

JWS is supplied by Oracle and works on Windows, *nix & OS X.

> ..but I would prefer not to use the Java Web Start. Because I would like to have a native installer that just installs the program, without opening a web page or anything. If that's not how (web start) works, then I'm happy to use it.

JWS works over the web or a network. But if you can invoke the opening of an URL (to the JNLP) from the desktop, there does not need to be any browser opened.

> Would I do that using `openConnection()` on a URL object?

I would use the [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) or [`BasicService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html) API.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);

boolean result = basicService.showDocument(url);
```

As noted in the [`BasicService` demo](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs).

> In Java 6+, a call to show another web start launch file (e.g. `BasicService.showDocument(another.jnlp))` will be handed directly to JavaWS, with no browser window appearing.

I expect this has always been true of the `Desktop` API, given the JWS client is the default consumer for that file type.