# invoke java web start from web (file-extension/mime-type associations)

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, systems-programming, regedit

I have created web start app (JNLP and jar file) it's already installed on my PC.

No I need to run this application from the servlet.

1) question. Can I invoke my java web start application from servlet? I need to run this, on my PC, I don't need java applet.

2) I think about ["file-extension/mime-type associations"](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#s226).  I mean that, for example if header contains x-application/aaa I need my jnlp file to be invoked on my pc.

```
<association extensions="aaa" mime-type="x-application/aaa"/>
```

But, Now I'm thinking , how can I call my jnlp?... Browser must find handler of my "xtype opener application", does not it? how can I do that?

If for example there is mime type of PDF, browser opens data with ADOBE READER. If there will be mime type of my application, I need to invoke my jnlp. How can I register my application as an opener application?

I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556476/associating-a-custom-file-extension-with-java-app-in-windows) but in the web.

Comment: From the servlet you could use redirect to a place where jnlp can be downloaded from. From there is up to the client's browser and java.

Comment: No, I don't need this. I need to register my own mime type and then call this.

Comment: I need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556476/associating-a-custom-file-extension-with-java-app-in-windows) but in the web

Comment: Doesn't it have to be registered in the browser/OS?

Comment: I don't know.  I think about it...