# Java - How to To Reserve a File Extension

Tags: java, file-extension

I have looked everywhere and I can't find how to do this.
When you open a Microsoft Word .docx file, it opens directly to Microsoft Word.
I want to be able to do that with my program. Whenever someone opens a .ewf or .esf file, I want it to open up in my program.

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs) might help... If not I assume it works with registry entries where I cannot tell you more about unfortunately.

Comment: See this prior SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556476/associating-a-custom-file-extension-with-java-app-in-windows

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful!